# Add a responsive background image to a division class bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to use a javascript function inside an image.Hence i would like to add the image as background-image in a division class.I want it to be responsive and scalable just like the `<img>` tag that i use. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS3 **background-size** can be used here.

```
background-size: [auto|percentage|units - for width] [auto|percentage|units - for height];
```

For example:

```
.bg{
    /*will stretch the element's background to its full width (saving proportions of the picture - so it may be cut vertically or not fill the entire height):*/
    background-size:100% auto;

    /*will stretch the element's background to its full height (it may be cut - this time - horizontally or not fill the entire width):*/
    background-size:auto 100%;

    /* the background will be forced to the 50% of the el's width and 40% of its height respectively: */
    background-size:50% 40%;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate. The above code shall be pasted as it is or do i have to add something to it

Comment: @user3274745 added a couple of examples.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I had decided to use another javascript function but still i'll give you a vote up